# cuando intento renderizar un usestate hook en react el navegador me da un error de sintaxis pero el vs code no detecta ningun error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate, jest, componentes

Cuando intento renderizar el main.jsx me da ese error el console del navegador. Cabe destacar que antes funcioanaba bien  y no he realizado ningún cambio en los componentes.Empezó a comportarse hace así después de  configurar jest y babel como ambiente de pruebas De igual manera les dejo los componentes involucrados y el repositorio a ver si me pueden ayudar con este error tan extraño por favor

https://github.com/carloslml90/unitarytest.git

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MAIN.JSX

```
import  React  from "react";
import  ReactDOM  from "react-dom/client";

import "./Styles.css";

import { CounterApp } from "./CounterApp";



ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(

<React.StrictMode>
<CounterApp value={10} />
</React.StrictMode>

)
```

COUNTERAPP

```
import { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";




 export const CounterApp=({value}) =>{
    
    const [counter,setCounter]=useState(value);

    const HandleAdd=()  =>  {
        setCounter((c) => c + 10)
    };

    const HandleLess=()  =>  {
        setCounter((c) => c - 10)
    };

    const HandleReset=()  =>  {
        setCounter((c) => value)
    };

return (
<>
    <h1>CounterApp</h1>
    <h2>{counter}</h2>

    <center>
        <button onClick={HandleAdd}> +1</button>
        <button onClick={HandleLess}> -1</button>
        <button onClick={HandleReset}> Reset</button>
        </center>
    </>
);

}

CounterApp.propTypes={

    value: PropTypes.number,
}
```

Comment: Buen dia! creo que el problema esta en la linea de la importacion de ReactDOM. vos pusiste import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
pero lo correcto es importala desde "react-dom", osea, import ReactDOM from "react-dom"; fijate si esto te lo soluciona. Saludos!